# Parse JSON string into DataSet

Tags: c#, vb.net, json, c#-4.0

I have to the replication.That time have to pass String as JSON

```
{"Table1" : 
    [
        {"Name" : "MyCustomer","Description" : "cutomer","Status" : "1"},             {"Name" : "Kiraa","Description" : "My","Status" : "1",}
    ]
}
```

This is my format of JSON result. I want to convert to DataSet.

I have installed JSON.NET library. I am using C#.net

```
public bool convertJSONToDataSet(string strBusinessUnit, string strExecutiveCode, string strTableName, String jsonContent)
{
    DataSet dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(jsonContent);
    return true;
}
```

here this statement is wrong `DataSet dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(jsonContent);`.What is the issue. Please tell me how to covert to a JSON string to a Dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create an object to deserialize to.

```
class Customer
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

You can then deserialize objects like this:

```
Customer customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(jsonContent);
```

As far as I'm concerned, you can then add multiple `Customer` objects into a list, dataset or whatever you like.